# eclipse plugin for generate UML from php

Tags: eclipse-plugin, uml

i use latest eclipse helios for php version,
by now i want to learn generateing UML from my project.

Any one can suggest me what is the recommended plugin to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[StarUML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/templates.php) has a php5 generator template which can be edited to suit your needs.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion ..
i'll learn about uml it self, then i'll start to try this plugin